# Cognito with SAML IdP (Azure AD), refresh_token still works after user is removed from AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, saml

I am implementing login with SSO using Cognito and a SAML Identity provider.
To test it, I have created a test app in Azure AD and I've added a test user to it so it can login.
I have implemented the callback in my webapp to receive the code with which I get the tokens.

Everything seems to be working correctly however, if the user is removed from Azure (e.g. this person stops working for the organization) the adminInitiateAuth call with the refresh_token still works.

I would have expected that this call would fail if the user is removed from the AD App.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a workaround for me to know from my webapp if a user is removed from the IdP and prevent this user from log in?

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. In fact, during the [lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-token-lifetime-properties-after-the-retirement) of the access token or refresh token, they are all available.

If you want the access token to expire immediately, you can use power shell:  [Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-revoke-access#azure-active-directory-environment),     or AAD Graph API : `POST https://graph.windows.net/{tenant id}/me/invalidateAllRefreshTokens?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1` revokes the refresh token.

By the way, the access token cannot be revoked and it will automatically expire after 1 hour.